# How to color specific Vim tabs

Tags: vim

I program a complex system which consists of different components.
When I do investigation I usually open code of different components in different tabs. So switching over tabs I look through interface and its implementation in different components (most of them are written in C). When number of tabs exceeds 7 it becomes difficult to distinguish them. I would like to color tabs of each components in their dedicated color, e.g. three tabs are green, other 4 tabs are yellow, and the last 3 tabs are blue. I am okay to set color of each tab manually.
Could you tell me how can I achieve this?
Thanks